# Java Scanner Function - How do I grab a certain word or words from inside a string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

So, I'm reading in a line of text into a scanner variable, an example looks something like this:

```
    Scanner strLine = new Scanner("Peter has red hair and is very tall");
```

I want to then pull out certain aspects of the string and apply it to individual String variables:

```
    String name = "Peter"
    String hairColor = "red hair"
    String height = "very tall"
```

I've tried 'for' statements that look for the words "has" and then grab the next 2 words with:

```
    String hairColor = strLine.next() + strLine.next();
```

Is there an easier way to read in a line of text and pull individual information out of it other than Scanner?

Thank you.

Comment: What you're essential asking for is a natural language processor, no?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that or how that applies to what I'm trying to do?

Comment: This is a custom requirement and needs to be handled explicitly. Either split the data and put in an array for further use or check for regex pattern if the data is not going to deviate much with the format.

Comment: An _easier_ way than `Scanner`? It's a judgement call.  Let us just say there are alternatives which **aren't any harder**.

Comment: Basicallly... Is the pattern **always** `(name) has (hair-description) and is (height-description)`... If so you, can use a regular expression. Otherwise, what if you had `(name) is (height-description) and has (hair-description)`...? What if you had no information about height and hair... If someone went bald and "had hair". My point is that recognizing parts of speech is far broader than the question you are asking

Answer (score 0):

I would use split and then dump the results into a List

```
    String text = "Peter has red hair and is very tall";
    List<String> words = Arrays.asList(text.split(" "));
    int hasIndex = words.indexOf("has");
    if (hasIndex != -1) {
        System.out.println(words.get(hasIndex + 1) + " " + words.get(hasIndex + 2));
    }
```

Of course care should be taken for Out Of Bounds Errors